# How to create a CSR request with Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, csr, pkcs#10

The current situation is that we get the public key from the USBKEY, but we need to use the private key to sign the CSR request. I don't know how to do that

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LydU.png)

The data in the red circle is the public key we get from USBKEY, but kp.getPrivate() I think it should be wrong.

This is the code to generate China GM CSR

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
package com.xf.face.util;

import fisher.man.util.encoders.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500NameBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.style.BCStyle;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEECPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.pkcs.jcajce.JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder;
import sun.security.util.CurveDB;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPoint;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * @ Author     ：焦康
 * @ Date       ：Created in 9:35 2021/4/6
 * @ Description：国密证书csr请求
 */
public class SM2CsrUtil {


    //国密推荐256位曲线参数
    private static final String P_STR = "FFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
    private static final String A_STR = "FFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC";
    private static final String B_STR = "28E9FA9E9D9F5E344D5A9E4BCF6509A7F39789F515AB8F92DDBCBD414D940E93";
    private static final String N_STR = "FFFFFFFEFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7203DF6B21C6052B53BBF40939D54123";
    //base point
    private static final String X_STR = "32C4AE2C1F1981195F9904466A39C9948FE30BBFF2660BE1715A4589334C74C7";
    private static final String Y_STR = "BC3736A2F4F6779C59BDCEE36B692153D0A9877CC62A474002DF32E52139F0A0";
    private static final String SPLIT_PATTERN = ",|\\[|\\]";
    /**
     * 算法提供者 Bouncy Castle
     */
    private static final Provider BC = new BouncyCastleProvider();

    public static String genCSR(String subject, String alg, String provider, byte[] pkdata) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, OperatorCreationException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException {

        String signalg = "";
        int alglength = 0;
        String keyAlg = "";
        String hexString = null;
        if (alg.toUpperCase().equals("RSA1024")) {
            signalg = "SHA1WithRSA";
            alglength = 1024;
            keyAlg = "RSA";
        } else if (alg.toUpperCase().equals("RSA2048")) {
            // signalg = "SHA1WithRSA";
            signalg = "1.2.840.10045.4.1";
            alglength = 2048;
            keyAlg = "RSA";
        } else if (alg.toUpperCase().equals("SM2")) {
            // signalg = "ECDSAWITHSHA1";
            signalg = "SM3withSM2";
            alglength = 256;
            keyAlg = "EC";
        }
        org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
        Provider t[] = Security.getProviders();
        Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);
        Provider t1[] = Security.getProviders();
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(keyAlg,BC);
        keyGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("sm2p256v1"));
        KeyPair kp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        byte[] heradByte = new byte[]{48, 89, 48, 19, 6, 7, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 2, 1, 6, 8, 42, -122, 72, -50, 61, 3, 1, 7, 3, 66, 0, 4};
        byte[] data = byteMerger(heradByte, pkdata);

        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder builder = new PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(new X500Name(subject), SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(data));
        JcaContentSignerBuilder jcaContentSignerBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signalg).setProvider("BC");
        ContentSigner contentSigner = jcaContentSignerBuilder.build(kp.getPrivate());
        PKCS10CertificationRequest Request = builder.build(contentSigner);
        try {
            byte[] encoded2 = Request.getEncoded();
            hexString = new String(Base64.encode(encoded2));
            System.out.println(hexString.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", ""));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return hexString;
    }

    //System.arraycopy()方法
    public static byte[] byteMerger(byte[] bt1, byte[] bt2) {
        byte[] bt3 = new byte[bt1.length + bt2.length];
        System.arraycopy(bt1, 0, bt3, 0, bt1.length);
        System.arraycopy(bt2, 0, bt3, bt1.length, bt2.length);
        return bt3;
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws OperatorCreationException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchProviderException {
        try {
            //add sm2p256v1 support to EC CurveDB
            Pattern localPattern = Pattern.compile(SPLIT_PATTERN);
            Class[] argTypes = {
                    String.class, String.class, int.class, String.class, String.class,
                    String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, int.class, Pattern.class};
            Object[] argss = new Object[]{
                    "sm2p256v1", "1.2.156.10197.1.301",
                    1, P_STR, A_STR, B_STR, X_STR, Y_STR, N_STR, 1, localPattern};
            Method add = CurveDB.class.getDeclaredMethod("add", argTypes);
            add.setAccessible(true);
            add.invoke(CurveDB.class, argss);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        String dn = "CN=TEST";
        String pkStr = "AAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAv/pInHHFzGAdhIRGDKOc2bjq9I3SUGIOIcMRwgMSpqEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIWXe67pEetAHBkEPY2Mi5B1TLu0+fH0z5gosfV21aUO";
        byte[] pkdata = Base64.decode(pkStr);
        byte[] x = new byte[32];
        byte[] y = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(pkdata, 36, x, 0, 32);
        System.arraycopy(pkdata, 36 + 32 + 32, y, 0, 32);
        byte[] data = byteMerger(x, y);
        String csr = genCSR(dn, "SM2", "CA", data);
        System.out.println("生成的CSR:" + csr);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use code snippets instead of images. This increases your chance of getting help since nobody wants to copy code from an image.

Comment: sorry,Now I've added runnable code

Comment: The usual way is to generate a key pair and store them anywhere (e.g. on a USB stick). The next step is to generate the CSR with this key pair. It looks like that you mix the public key from USB stick with a fresh generated private key ("KeyPair kp = keyGen.generateKeyPair();") that won't work. Get already generated private key from your stick, import it and use it as input.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, as you said, I should generate CSR from USBKEY. This problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved. CSR should be generated in USBKEY. This problem has been solved

Comment: If you are looking to generate CSR and Download Certificate from web application, please refer stackoverflow.com/a/68556286/9659885